# Google policies and restrictions on developing finance android apps

Tags: android

I am supposed to develop android app that include some purchasing requirements. I am going to add separate web view to the app and i load a web page(via url) into my app's web view so users can purchase from my app's web view via above web page. So my problem is what are the Google policies and restrictions on developing such an app.I have search it on Google and i could not find out a good explanation exactly address my situation and som of them were complicated so any one can simply explain those things??

Any Explanation highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I'm pretty sure</strike> the only restriction is to not do something like "in-app" purchases so if you're selling goods or a service that has nothing to do with an app, you're fine.

Details at http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

> Developers offering additional content, services or functionality
>   within an application downloaded from Google Play **must use Google
>   Play's payment system** as the method of payment, except: where payment
>   is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g. buying movie
>   tickets; e.g. buying a publication where the price also includes a
>   hard copy subscription); or where payment is for digital content or
>   goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g.
>   buying songs that can be played on other music players)